# How can i remove the unwanted files with tilde mark using linux command?

Tags: linux, files, find, rm

Here I want to remove all tilde files from my directories and subdirectories . How can I use the linux command here?

Tree Structure:

```
.
|-- Block_Physical_design_checklist
|   |-- Block_Physical_design_checklist.config
|   |-- Block_Physical_design_checklist.html
|   |-- Block_Physical_design_checklist.html~
|   `-- rev6
|       |-- rev6.config
|       `-- rev6.html
|-- CAD_checklist
|   |-- CAD_checklist.config
|   |-- CAD_checklist.html
|   |-- CAD_checklist.html~
|   `-- rev6
|       |-- rev6.config
|       `-- rev6.html
|-- Formality_DCT_Vs_ICC
|   |-- Formality_DCT_Vs_ICC.config
|   |-- Formality_DCT_Vs_ICC.html
|   |-- Formality_DCT_Vs_ICC.html~
|   `-- rev6
|       |-- rev6.config
|       |-- rev6.html
|       `-- rev6.html~
```

Expected Tree Structure:

```
.
|-- Block_Physical_design_checklist
|   |-- Block_Physical_design_checklist.config
|   |-- Block_Physical_design_checklist.html
|   `-- rev6
|       |-- rev6.config
|       `-- rev6.html
|-- CAD_checklist
|   |-- CAD_checklist.config
|   |-- CAD_checklist.html
|   `-- rev6
|       |-- rev6.config
|       `-- rev6.html
|-- Formality_DCT_Vs_ICC
|   |-- Formality_DCT_Vs_ICC.config
|   |-- Formality_DCT_Vs_ICC.html
|   `-- rev6
|       |-- rev6.config
|       |-- rev6.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach `find . -type f -name '*~' -exec rm -f '{}' \;` has couple of issues/improvement scopes:

- `-name '*~'` matches only files ending in  `~`; if you want to match any file containing `~`, use `*~*`
- `-exec rm -f '{}' \;` is spawning `rm` for each file, which is clumsy and inefficient; instead, as `rm` can take multiple files as arguments, you can tell `find ... -exec` to get as many files in one go without triggering the `ARG_MAX` using the `+` argument to `-exec`

Putting these two together:

```
find . -type f -name '*~*' -exec rm -f {} +
```

---

If you happen to have GNU `find`, you can use the `-delete` action:

```
find . -type f -name '*~*' -delete
```

---

In `zsh`, you can do recursive pattern matching and removal in one go like:

```
rm -f -- **/*~*(.)
```

the glob modifier `.` matches only regular files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer,

```
find . -type f -name '*~' -exec rm -f '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash's `globstar` option:

```
shopt -s globstar ; rm ./**/*~
```

`globstar` allows for recursive globbing with `**`, while `./` prevents issues with filenames that might have a leading `-` in them and `*~` will match filenames ending with tilde